# table not being set in eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am having some issues setting my table in an eloquent model. I have done this many times before but for some reason this doesn't seem to be working. am I missing something completely here?

Model:

```
class F5Host extends Eloquent {


   protected $guarded = array();
   protected $table = 'f5hosts';


   public function Environments() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Environment');
   }

}
```

Usage:

```
  $host = new F5Host;
  return $host->all();
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myapp.f5_hosts' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `f5_hosts`)
```

Update:
I know Laravel has a feature that translates CamelCase to snake_case when using models to determine the DB table name. however the $table variable should override this. I noticed when changing the class name to "F5host" all of a sudden the override begins working.

Comment: make sure that `myapp` database contains `f5_hosts` table

Comment: The model setup looks fine. I'm not sure about this, but can you try `F5Host::all()` instead of `$host = new F5Host; return $host->all();`

Comment: @Razor f5_hosts does not exist that is why I am trying to change the name to 'f5hosts'

Comment: @lukasgeiter that returns the same result

Comment: Okay. Are you sure this line causes the error? Does it go away if you remove it / comment it out?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the error is caused because it is trying to access a non existent DB.  I am specifying the correct DB name but laravel does not seem to be setting it. I have used this method of changing a table name before and it works. it is also specified in the documentation.

Comment: I know that it should work... I wanted to make sure that `$host->all()` is actually where the error is happening and not some other code. Also you can try `$host->getTable()` and see what it returns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67506/discussion-between-arrowill12-and-lukasgeiter).

Answer (score 0):

Create Environment class model

Example

```
class Environment extends Eloquent {


   protected $guarded = array();
   protected $table = 'environment';


   public function f5hosts() {
      return $this->hasOne('F5Host');
   }

}
```

Change relation methods and test.

Sory: My English is not good.

Comment: this model already exists. I am not having any issues with the Environment model or the relationship

Comment: view link http://php-problems.blogspot.com.tr/2013/08/sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not.html